# Converting ALAC inside .mp4 file to FLAC without quality loss with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, mp4, flac, alac

So, I have a .mp4 video file recorded with OBS, and I realised that Sony Vegas does not accept the audio format because it is from Apple (it basically imports the video just fine, but the audio is 6 empty channels even though playing through VLC plays the audio flawlessly).

I need the recorded audio to be converted lossless to FLAC, and all I can find online is FFmpeg. I've tried using it, but I lack the knowledge to properly set up the conversion code path thingy.

I recorded it as a video file with audio settings set to:

- **FFmpeg ALAC 24-bit**
- **audio bitrate: 1024 kbps**
- **5.1 surround (6 channels)**

I want the FLAC audio file to be exactly the above settings with no quality loss. Can anyone help me, or is there perhaps a better program to do this? VLC only allows to convert FLAC to 512kbps which is half the original quality.

Comment: How could it be half the quality if both codecs are lossless? How are you losing quality with lossless codecs?

Comment: I recorded the audio at 1024kbps. VLC would only allow me to convert the .mp4 with FLAC settings at 512kbps (hence the comment about half the quality). It would halve the amounts of bytes per second, that means it degrades the quality, no?